# changing wordpress theme php file has no effect

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have a WP deployment on my devbox. I have downloaded some new custom theme, which works great, and it has some php files I want to change. Some of the php files appear under settings->appearence->editor, but some are not. If I want to change a php file that is NOT in the list, I use Notepad++ to edit and save it. However, the changes I make to it are not reflected in the page... I have no caching plugins installed, and even if I do (I tried WP Super Cache) and I clear the cache, it does not help.

For example, I am editing the service_box.php file that is part of the Cherry framework theme, I save it, but stlil my page (using the [service_box] shortcode) does not show the changes.

Note: if I change something through the WP editor, it DOES take effect, however, I can only do this for files that actually appear in the editor file list, and in my case, the file does not appear there, maybe because it is in some sub/subfolder of the theme, I really don't know..

Any ideas how to make the changes effective?
tnx

Comment: if you edit the files that appear in wp editor with Notepad++ does it take effect too?

Comment: Changing files that appear, using notepad also has no effect. I am trying to modify the cherry service_box shortcode behavior (minor change to add some link).

Comment: Add some uniq text (for example your name) to file using editor and than find file with this uniq text directly (to open in Notepad). Maybe you work on two different files with the same name in two different folders. Is your "devbox" on your local computer ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you do not have the right permissions to edit the file directly.  Editing the file in WPress would work b/c it 'owns' the file.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, it seems I was able to resolve this as follows:
I installed the WP Editor plugin, which lets you edit any theme file - not just the ones in the top folder. So now I can edit any file directly from WP and not from an external editor
I tried the "clear cache" in WP Super cache again - this time it seemed to help. Without clearing the cache, the changes would not take effect.

note: this was NOT a permission issue, as the files on disk were accessible and I was able to save the changes and load them later back into the external editor...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework like Cherry, you cannot edit their files. Each time you save something in the Admin area of Wordpress some of your files will be re-compiled and you will lose those changes. In order to make design or function changes to your active theme, you must be doing all changes within the child-theme files. If there are functions you want to change within the framework that aren't currently included in your template, you must use wordpress Hooks, (Actions and Filters) on functions from the framework directly into your child-theme.

Once you have that all taken care of, cherry includes a clear cache button on the top admin bar that should help clear out old versions of the file sitting on your server.